# How to insert an index of an array to another array through conditions in java

Tags: java, arrays

Write a java program that has 3 arrays. The first array will store lists of random integer values from 50 to 100. The program will identify passed and failed values. The second array will contain all passed values. And the third array will contain all the failed values. Required input includes size of array and passing grade. The outputs are the following: the original list, list of passed grades, and list of failed grades.
I know this is not the best code, but please do help me. I have done my research but this is all I've got.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class array {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

    int size;
    int passing;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Size of Array: ");
    size = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Passing Grade: ");
    passing = input.nextInt();

    int [] score = new int [size];
    int [] passed= new int [size];
    int [] failed= new int [size];

    int index = 0;
    int max = 100;
    int min = 50;

    System.out.print("Original List:\n");
    for(int a =0; a<=score.length; a++){
        score[a] = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max-min) + 1) );
        System.out.print(score[a] + "\n");
    }

    System.out.print("Passed Values:\n");
    for(int a=1; a<=score.length; a++){
        if (score[a] >= passing){
            int res = (passed[index++] = score[a]);
            System.out.print(res + "\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Failed Values:\n");
    for(int a=1; a<=score.length; a++){
        if (score[a] <passing){
            failed[index++] = score[a];
            int res2 = (passed[index++] = score[a]);
            System.out.print(res2 + "\n");
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: You're consistently indexing outside your arrays. The largest valid index is `array.length - 1`.

Comment: Given that you've put in some effort here, I'll throw you a bone.  use two separate indices; `passIndex` and `failIndex` for the `passed` and `failed` arrays, respectively.  Use `<` instead of `<=` for you maximum `a` value. split up the `res` calculation from putting it in the array.  you can use `println` instead of `print` to handle the new line.  The "fail" loop could just be an `else` condition on the loop before it.  You reference `passed` in your fail loop for unknown reasons.

Comment: Normally though, if you're going to post questions on StackOverflow, you want to deal with **specific** problems.  Break down your problem, and, if you can't solve a specific chunk of the problem, ask SO for help.  Questions like this that basically say "here's my code it doesn't work" are often poorly received.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found three main issues, for loop should check for `a<score.length` instead of `a<=score.length`. Second and third for loop initial condition should be `a=0` instead of `a=1`. After execution of second for loop you should reset `index` variable to `0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            int size;
            int passing;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Size of Array: ");
            size = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Passing Grade: ");
            passing = input.nextInt();

            int [] score = new int [size];
            int [] passed= new int [size];
            int [] failed= new int [size];

            int index = 0;
            int max = 100;
            int min = 50;

            System.out.print("Original List:\n");
            for(int a =0; a<score.length; a++){
                score[a] = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max-min) + 1) );
                System.out.print(score[a] + "\n");
            }

            System.out.print("Passed Values:\n");
            for(int a=0; a<score.length; a++){
                if (score[a] >= passing){
                    int res = (passed[index++] = score[a]);
                    System.out.print(res + "\n");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Failed Values:\n");
            index = 0;
            for(int a=0; a<score.length; a++){
                if (score[a] <passing){
                    failed[index++] = score[a];
                    int res2 = (passed[index++] = score[a]);
                    System.out.print(res2 + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And yeah I forgot to change the a=1 to a=0 before I posted it. Thank you.